# Auto navigation in windows registry editor?

Tags: windows-registry, console

Is there any tweak to open a particular registry key in registry editor from console/command mode ?

Say like If I want to view this key in registry editor

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Current Version
```

After opening regedit.exe, I would like to auto navigate to this key.

Note: I checked reg.exe , but its pure console application of registry editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind downloading a tiny program, Microsoft Sysinternals have a tool called [Regjump](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963880.aspx)

Simply download this anywhere (I put it in the windows\system32 folder so it has path) then from anywhere, just type:

```
regjump HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion
```

Or

```
regjump HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion
```

Remember that Current Version path does not have a space, however if there is a space in the name, simply put the entire path in to quotes, for example

```
regjump "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Current Version"
```

Only downside to this application is that you need to run it in an elevated command prompt or turn compatibility on and make sure that regjump always runs as elevated (If you have UAC on). If you do not do this, it will load registry editor, but it will be unable to *tell* when it is launched and will not jump to the path.

Comment: Cool ;) this is what i was looking for